# Symfony Sonata Project - filter type using date picker but not a range - just a single date picker

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I'm using Sonata to render a listing page for an entity.

I want to filter results using one of the columns that holds a date and time. I want to use date picker for better UX. My problem is that [none of the official filter types support a single date picker field](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html#available-filter-types).

If you will scroll to section 5.1 the documentation gives a bunch of options:

> 5.1. AVAILABLE FILTER TYPES
>
> For now, only Doctrine ORM filters are available:
>   (...)

but none is able to render a single input. Always a range made of 2 inputs is rendered - I don't need that. I just need **a single** field.

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper->add('dateStart', 'NONE_OF_THE_TYPES_GIVE_ME_A_SINGLE_PICKER_INPUT', [
        // other args
    ]);
}
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('date', 'doctrine_orm_datetime', [
            'label'         => 'Date',
            'field_type'    => 'sonata_type_datetime_picker',
            'field_options' => [
                'widget' => 'single_text',
            ]
    ]);
}
```